# Need help to identify this baroque keyboard sonata

Tags: classical-music, baroque

I only have the 25 seconds of a baroque piece. It sounds like harpsichord but I'm not sure and it also sounds like E minor. I have been looking for it for years no success.

I tried to search E minor harpsichord sonatas from varies artist but couldn't find this piece. Shazam couldn't find it either.

https://soundcloud.com/mete-uyar-302753884

I don't know what to do more.

Comment: I guess, this is Johann Sebastian Bach. He wrote nothing for keyboard called *sonata* however, so I would search within his well-tempered clavier, partitas and inventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good guess, guidot!

It's one of Bach's [*6 Little Preludes "zur Anfanger auf dem Clavier"*](https://imslp.org/wiki/6_Kleine_Pr%C3%A4ludien%2C_BWV_933-938_(Bach%2C_Johann_Sebastian)) : N° 6 in e minor (BWV 938).

Your extract starts in [measure 26](http://ks4.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/d/d2/IMSLP242192-PMLP180600-BWV938.pdf).